# C++ Constructors Array Error

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to implement a program where I'm supposed to read input from a text file which is formatted as string,integer,integer in lines and store these values in an array/vector.

Header file:

```
class Datastructure
{
public:
  Datastructure();
  ~Datastructure();

  int index;

  struct player
  {
    std::string name;
    int bus_number;
    int passenger_number;
  };

  player * player_array = new player[100];
}
```

.cpp file:

```
Datastructure::Datastructure()
{
    index=0;
}

//Add new players
void Datastructure::add(std::string name, unsigned int brokenBus,
            unsigned int sufferingPeople)
{
    player_array[index].name = name;
    player_array[index].bus_number = brokenBus;
    player_array[index].passenger_number = sufferingPeople;

    //this part works correctly
    std::cout<<player_array[index].name<<","<<player_array[index].bus_number<<","<<
    player_array[index].passenger_number<<std::endl;

    index++;
}

//Print all players
void Datastructure::printLeaderBoard()
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        //this part just prints random numbers
        std::cout<<player_array[i].name<<","<<player_array[i].bus_number<<","<<
        player_array[i].passenger_number<<","<<std::endl;
}
```

The problem here is that, the printing within `Datastructure::add()` function works correctly when it is run in main. But, the printing within `Datastructure::printLeaderBoard()` just prints out random numbers when it is run in main. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try terminating your for loop at `index` instead of 100.

Comment: Is this for a class?  Why haven't they taught you `vector` yet?  :(

Comment: It worked and solves my problem thank you! Quick question though, in my test program I was adding 23 elements to my array, just because I wasn't adding anything for the last 77 elements of the array, why was it still failing to print out the first 23 elements that I had added?

Comment: On a side note, you should practice keeping your variables in the private section of your class

Comment: @MertŞeker It's hard to say without seeing more of your code.

Comment: @Michael Albers Appereantly, it was printing out the elements that I had added when I was using 100 to terminate the loop, they were just dissappearing in the console due to the high amount of lines that were being printed. Funny how I didn't notice that.

Comment: @MertŞeker PEBCAK ;)